# Django / Div IDs

Tags: html, css, django, forms, post

I have a question about Django. When you configure your views to use a method of POST to get the information back from the client into your view/template can you also send over the div id's ?
The reason I ask is that I have a form with loads of information coming back from the client and want to be able to sort it (within Django) by the div id`s.

Thanks,

Comment: No. Forms post data in fields, not id's on arbitrary elements.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's possible. You can add a hidden input field which contains the value of the div id. Just put the following within the `<form>` tags:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_id value="name_of_id">
```

You can now retrieve the value in your Django view.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative but similar solution is to give the button, to post the form with, the name of the div id.

```
<button type="submit" value="div id" name="div id">Submit</button>
```